# Problem with F# Powerpack. Method not found error

Tags: f#, powerpack

I've had F# Powerpack for a while now. It ran perfectly. But a few days before, I don't know what I did, whenever I compile my project and run it, I get an error

```
Method not found: 'System.Object Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Parsing.Tables`1.Interpret(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer`1<Char>,!0>, Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer`1<Char>, Int32)'.
```

I tried on my laptop too. Then I thought, that it might be an error in my code. So I started a new project, F# Parsed Language Starter Kit (the starter kit you find online), and it fails with the same error. I tried reinstalling F# Powerpack but the error continues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably installed VS2010 SP1. 
http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2011/03/dont-install-vs2010-sp1.html

Comment: Yes I did! Thank you, I was getting late for my academic project!

Answer (score 3):

Please send details of your install configuration and updates to fsbugs AT microsoft.com.

Also, please repair Visual Studio, and/or look at the instructions [on this page](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/discussions/238389?ProjectName=fsharppowerpack) and send us the contents of your `pub.config` file.

A workaround to get you going again is to recompile the F# Power Pack for .NET 4.0 (it is a .NET 2.0 binary, and this related to the issue you're seeing)

Comment: Regarding the proposed workaround, I've built the Power Pack against the 4.0 CLR and strongly signed the assemblies (so they can be installed into the GAC), and have not seen this issue after installing SP1. If anyone wants the binaries without building everything from scratch, I've uploaded them here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10282384/FSPowerPackCLR4SP1.7z

Comment: I've raised a bug for this against fsyacc (http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/workitem/5991) though from what ildjarn says it might be a CLR issue more than a fsyacc issue.

Comment: I have added a comment to the bug @itowlson raised on codeplex, with a fix suggested by dsyme.  It worked for me. See [link](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/workitem/5991)

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same error when trying to build [WikiBooks Lexing/Parsing example](https://github.com/obeleh/FsYacc-Example) in Visual Studio 2012. I resolved the problem by switching target framework from 4.0 to 4.5 in project settings.

Comment: This solution helped me too and i think it is the easiest one. Thank you